Installation Xdebug on MacOS Sonoma failed
I try to install xdebug with xdebug install guide on my mac(sonoma 14.5),but it failed，
error:
/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/xdebug.c:18:10: fatal error: 'config.h' file not found
#include "config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [xdebug.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

here is more info of my env:
➜  ~ file `which php`
/usr/local/opt/php@8.1/bin/php: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
➜  ~ php -v
PHP 8.1.29 (cli) (built: Jun  5 2024 05:51:57) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.29, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.29, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

intstall with below command:
arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install xdebug

full install message:
➜  ~ arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install xdebug
Password:
downloading xdebug-3.3.2.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-3.3.2.tgz (258,943 bytes)
.....................................................done: 258,943 bytes
102 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20210902
Zend Module Api No:      20210902
Zend Extension Api No:   420210902
building in /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootjXsivk/xdebug-3.3.2
running: /private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php@8.1/bin/php-config
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... no
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for egrep -e... (cached) /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin23.5.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin23.5.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin23.5.0
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/main -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/pecl/20210902
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking whether to enable Xdebug support... yes, shared
checking whether to enable Xdebug developer build flags... no
checking whether to compress profiler files (requires zlib)... yes
checking for supported PHP version... supported (8.1.29)
checking for clock_gettime... yes
checking for clock_gettime_nsec_np... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking for sys/poll.h... yes
checking for res_ninit... no
checking for __res_ninit... no
checking for res_ninit in -lresolv... no
checking for __res_ninit in -lresolv... no
checking for res_nclose... no
checking for __res_nclose... no
checking for res_nclose in -lresolv... no
checking for __res_nclose in -lresolv... no
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for zlib >= 1.2.9... no
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for ld used by cc... /Applications/Xcode-15.4.0.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode-15.4.0.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for /Applications/Xcode-15.4.0.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 786432
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for -single_module linker flag... ld: warning: -single_module is obsolete
yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fno-common
checking if cc PIC flag -fno-common works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... no
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/Applications/Xcode-15.4.0.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin23.5.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: patching config.h.in
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
running: make
Makefile:244: warning: overriding commands for target `test'
Makefile:136: warning: ignoring old commands for target `test'
/bin/sh /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootjXsivk/xdebug-3.3.2/libtool --mode=compile cc -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootjXsivk/xdebug-3.3.2/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootjXsivk/xdebug-3.3.2/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/main -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/src -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootjXsivk/xdebug-3.3.2/src  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2     -DZEND_COMPILE_DL_EXT=1 -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/xdebug.c -o xdebug.lo  -MMD -MF xdebug.dep -MT xdebug.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootjXsivk/xdebug-3.3.2/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootjXsivk/xdebug-3.3.2/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/main -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/src -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootjXsivk/xdebug-3.3.2/src -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -DZEND_COMPILE_DL_EXT=1 -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/xdebug.c -MMD -MF xdebug.dep -MT xdebug.lo  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/xdebug.o
/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/xdebug.c:18:10: fatal error: 'config.h' file not found
#include "config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [xdebug.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
➜  ~ arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install xdebug
Password:
downloading xdebug-3.3.2.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-3.3.2.tgz (258,943 bytes)
.....................................................done: 258,943 bytes
102 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20210902
Zend Module Api No:      20210902
Zend Extension Api No:   420210902
building in /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootZyukFz/xdebug-3.3.2
running: /private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php@8.1/bin/php-config
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... no
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for egrep -e... (cached) /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin23.5.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin23.5.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin23.5.0
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/main -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/pecl/20210902
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking whether to enable Xdebug support... yes, shared
checking whether to enable Xdebug developer build flags... no
checking whether to compress profiler files (requires zlib)... yes
checking for supported PHP version... supported (8.1.29)
checking for clock_gettime... yes
checking for clock_gettime_nsec_np... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking for sys/poll.h... yes
checking for res_ninit... no
checking for __res_ninit... no
checking for res_ninit in -lresolv... no
checking for __res_ninit in -lresolv... no
checking for res_nclose... no
checking for __res_nclose... no
checking for res_nclose in -lresolv... no
checking for __res_nclose in -lresolv... no
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for zlib >= 1.2.9... no
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for ld used by cc... /Applications/Xcode-15.4.0.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode-15.4.0.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for /Applications/Xcode-15.4.0.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 786432
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for -single_module linker flag... ld: warning: -single_module is obsolete
yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fno-common
checking if cc PIC flag -fno-common works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... no
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/Applications/Xcode-15.4.0.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin23.5.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: patching config.h.in
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
running: make
Makefile:244: warning: overriding commands for target `test'
Makefile:136: warning: ignoring old commands for target `test'
/bin/sh /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootZyukFz/xdebug-3.3.2/libtool --mode=compile cc -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootZyukFz/xdebug-3.3.2/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootZyukFz/xdebug-3.3.2/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/main -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/src -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootZyukFz/xdebug-3.3.2/src  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2     -DZEND_COMPILE_DL_EXT=1 -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/xdebug.c -o xdebug.lo  -MMD -MF xdebug.dep -MT xdebug.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootZyukFz/xdebug-3.3.2/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootZyukFz/xdebug-3.3.2/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/main -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.29/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/src -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootZyukFz/xdebug-3.3.2/src -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -DZEND_COMPILE_DL_EXT=1 -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/xdebug.c -MMD -MF xdebug.dep -MT xdebug.lo  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/xdebug.o
/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/xdebug.c:18:10: fatal error: 'config.h' file not found
#include "config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [xdebug.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed


Did you install PHP from Homebrew, or just using the Apple stuff?
